# Gets "One or more of your tags are not allowed" when trying to create Open Graph action with friend tags

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Fairly new to Open Graph. I am able to post an action with (using the sample code from when I created the action on the dev app page):

```
curl -F 'access_token=xxx' \
-F 'chatter=http://samples.ogp.me/225477284175782' \
-F 'place=134676523236535' \
'https://graph.facebook.com/me/[my_app]:[my_action]'
```

Everything looks fine on my timeline.. But when I tried to add "friend tags" using this:

```
curl -F 'access_token=xxx' \
-F 'chatter=http://samples.ogp.me/225477284175782' \
-F 'place=134676523236535' \
-F 'tags=854450021' \
'https://graph.facebook.com/me/[my_app]:[my_action]'
```

I got this error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"One or more of your tags are not allowed."}}
```

What am I missing? does the user being tagged have to auth the app or something?

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, until the open graph is live (with Timeline) users can't be tagged unless they are an admin of the app. I think you also have to be friends with them too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Paul. I just tried it by adding another admin to my app, and was able to tag her.. would it work if the person is a "tester" or "developer". can't wait for the open graph stuff to become live. :)

Comment: Hasn't it became live? Issue still persists.

Comment: tags isn't allowed yet. They still need a bit more work on our end.